# Context menu makes list disappear

Tags: swiftui

I want to have a context menu to copy/paste tabular data.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ItemView()
            ItemView()
            ItemView()
        }
        .contextMenu {
            Button(action: {
            }){
                Text("Copy")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
      
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack{
            Text("Column 1")
            Spacer()
            Text("Column 2")
            Spacer()
            Text("Column 3")
        }
        
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews2: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

However, the list disappears when long pressing it. I tried using just `Text("Column 1")` to confirm that the Spacers weren't causing issues and the same thing happened.

[image: context menu]

It seems to work when using a `Grid`, but that requires iOS 16.

```
        Grid {
            GridRow {
                ItemView()
            }
            GridRow {
                ItemView()
            }
        }
        .contextMenu {
            Button(action: {
            }){
                Text("Copy")
            }
        }
```

Edit:

With light theme, it looks like the entire screen is getting selected.

[image: light theme]

Adding `.frame(maxHeight: 200)`

[image: 200 height]

[image: blank rectangle]

Sometimes it works, but I don't know what I did differently.

[image: worked]

Comment: Have you tried to put an embedded `VStack` in the List?

Comment: @MaykonMeneghel Yeah, but it didn't help. I also tried adding `.zIndex(100)`. What's strange is that sometimes it works, but I am not able to reproduce it consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the solution you are looking for:

```swift
...
var body: some View {
    List {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach((0...3), id: \.self) { _ in
                ItemView()
            }
        }
        .contextMenu {
            Button(action: {
            }){
                Text("Copy")
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

You need to call `contextMenu` in a view inside the list.